# Databricks: Run "init script" everytime a notebook is attached in a cluster

Tags: automation, databricks

In short, I want to run an init script whenever I attach a notebook to a cluster. Is this possible? I know I can have an init script when you start a cluster, but that’s not what I need.

The reason is that we use ADLS to assign rights to different folders. No need to get into the details there, but the main point is that we have to execute it every time we attach a notebook. So I’m looking for a way to automate this process.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible achieve, there is no concept of init-script or hook to execute when notebook is attached to a cluster.